# Making cmd runs one by one in java

Tags: java, windows, cmd

Is it possible to make java monitor if a cmd is done then runs another cmd?

For example...

```
btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent args)
        {
            try
            {   
                String command = "cmd /c start "+DetectDrive+"\\starting.bat";
                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            } 
            catch (IOException e1)
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(checkbox.isSelected())
            {
                try
                {   
                    String command = "cmd /c start "+DetectDrive+"\\Stage1.bat";
                    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
                } 
                catch (IOException e1)
                {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if(checkbox_1.isSelected())
            {
                try
                {   
                    String command = "cmd /c start "+DetectDrive+"\\Stage2.bat";
                    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
                } 
                catch (IOException e1)
                {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How do I make sure that once starting.bat finishing running in the cmd then if stage1 has been ticked then the stage1.bat will start running in the cmd???

And then after the stage1.bat finish running in the cmd, it will go backs to the code and check if stage2.bat is ticked, if it is, then stage2.bat will run.

Comment: Consider using `ProcessBuilder` of `Runtime.exec`.  You should be using the [`exec(String[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[])) variant as it will deal spaces within parameters better.  You should be reading the output of the process as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Process.waitFor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29), but add `/wait` to your command to make then new process wait for the batch process to stop.

For example:

```
String command = "cmd /c start /wait Stage1.bat";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
p.waitFor();
```

The new process creates a new batch process and then terminates without the `/wait`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Process.waitFor()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29). It will wait until the command ends.

Answer (score 0):

Process has a waitFor method

from the javadoc:
Causes the current thread to wait, if necessary, until the process represented by this Process object has terminated. 
This method returns immediately if the subprocess has already terminated. 
If the subprocess has not yet terminated, the calling thread will be blocked until the subprocess exits.